# Date population

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to get the next year's closedate using this formula.

```
IF(
    MONTH(CloseDate) = 2 && DAY(CloseDate) = 29,
    DATE(YEAR(CloseDate) + 1, 2, 28),
    DATE(YEAR(CloseDate) + 1, MONTH(CloseDate), DAY(CloseDate)) – 1
)
```

There is a syntax error in this case. Can I get a help?

> Use formula syntax: Enclose text and picklist value API names in double quotes : ("the_text"), include numbers without quotes : (25), show percentages as decimals: (0.10), and express date calculations in the standard format: (Today() + 7)

Also if this works I have to replace it by current date.
So I can use today and get the next year's current date: 12/1/2024

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to include the syntax error detail.

Comment: @PhilW Updated qn

Comment: I'm assuming this is referencing the `Opportunity` object's `CloseDate`?

Comment: @PhilW Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula would be better handled simply using:

```
ADDMONTHS(CloseDate, 12)
```

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_addmonths.htm&type=5):

> Returns the date that is the indicated number of months before or after a specified date. If the specified date is the last day of the month, the resulting date is the last day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same date component as the specified date.

Thus, you don't need to worry about 29th February since this is already handled for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked.